# Select duplicate records info

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a person table:

```
Phone     | Id1 | Id2 | Fname | Lname| Street
111111111 | A1 | 1000 | David | Luck | 123 Main Street
111111111 | A2 | 1001 | David | Luck | blank
111111111 | A3 | 1002 | David | Luck | blank
222222222 | B1 | 2000 | Smith | Nema | blank
333333333 | C1 | 3000 | Lanyn | Buck | 456 Street
```

I would like to have the result below:

```
Phone     | Id1 | Id2 | Fname | Lname| Street
111111111 | A1 | 1000 | David | Luck | 123 Main Street
222222222 | B1 | 2000 | Smith | Nema | blank
333333333 | C1 | 3000 | Lanyn | Buck | 456 Street
```

What SQL2008 query should I be using to pick the dup **phone** records that have street info? Thanks

Comment: Are they blank as in '', or blank as in 'blank'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to choose a particular row.  This is where the window function `row_number()` is most useful.  The challenge is finding the right `order by` clause:

```
select p.Phone, p.Id1, p.Id2, p.Fname, p.Lname, p.Street
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by phone
                                order by (case when street is not null then 0 else 1 end),
                                         id2
                               ) as seqnum
      from person p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1
```

The function `row_number()` assigns a sequential number to rows with the same value of `phone` (based on the `partition by` clause).  The one with non-blank street and lowest `id2` gets a value of 1.  If none exist, then the one with the lowest id2 gets the value.  That is the one chosen by the outer filter.

Answer (score 0):

If your street is blank (as in empty set '' or NULL) when not populated with an actual address, you can use this to get your results:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Person a
JOIN (SELECT Phone, MAX(Street)'Street' 
      FROM Person
      GROUP BY Phone
      )b
ON a.Phone = b.Phone
AND a.Street = b.Street
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2cd1/3/0)

If your street was literally the string 'Blank' then the above would not return the desired results.

Comment: thanks @Goat_CO, the street value either empty (blank) or NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM person a
JOIN ( SELECT Phone, Street, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Phone
       ORDER BY CASE WHEN street is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Rank'
       FROM Person
     )b
ON a.Phone = b.Phone
AND a.Street = b.Street
WHERE b.Rank = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select a.* from Table1 a
inner join 
(
   select distinct Phone  from Table1
   group by Phone
) as b
on a.Phone= b.Phone
```

Comment: This would output every record from Table1, additionally DISTINCT and GROUP BY are redundant.